# Setting a property to a specific node

Tags: neo4j

I've been caught in a web. I deleted a label from multiple labeled nodes. Now these nodes only have different ID, no properties to distinguish them and same 3 labels. How can i set a property to only one of these 3 nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you know id of node then

> start n=node({id}) set n.{propertyName} = {value}